# ¿Como hacer varias operaciones en una sola consulta con 2 tablas distintas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta en sql server, donde realizo un Count, 2 funciones de sumas y una función de promedio.
Si ejecuto la consulta a una sola tabla, el resultado es correcto. Pero si quiero obtener el resultado con las mismas funciones a otra tabla, entonces varia los resultados de la primera y segunda tabla.
¿Alguna idea de lo que esta pasando?

Estas son mis tablas que tengo:

Tabla cec2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla auto_tab1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla: auto_tab2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Query donde obtengo los datos de una sola tabla:

```
SELECT cec2.cec,
COUNT(DISTINCT auto_tab1.id_tab1) as count_tab1,
SUM(case when auto_tab1.fechaaten IS not null and auto_tab1.nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solconseguialch,
SUM(case when auto_tab1.fechaaten IS null and auto_tab1.nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solsinseguialch,
AVG(case when auto_tab1.fechaaten is not null and auto_tab1.nombre is not null then DATEDIFF(DAY, auto_tab1.fechacapt, auto_tab1.fechaaten) end) AS numdiasalch

FROM cec2
left join auto_tab1 on auto_tab1.cec = cec2.cec

group by cec2.cec
order by cec2.cec
```

Resultado del primer Query:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es correcta la información.

Query obteniendo datos con las mismas funciones de dos tablas:

```
SELECT cec2.cec,

COUNT(DISTINCT auto_tab1.id_tab1) as count_tab1,
SUM(case when auto_tab1.fechaaten IS not null and auto_tab1.nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solconseguialch,
SUM(case when auto_tab1.fechaaten IS null and auto_tab1.nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solsinseguialch,
AVG(case when auto_tab1.fechaaten is not null and auto_tab1.nombre is not null then DATEDIFF(DAY, auto_tab1.fechacapt, auto_tab1.fechaaten) end) AS numdiasalch,

COUNT(DISTINCT auto_tab2.id_tab2) as count_tab2,
SUM(case when auto_tab2.fechaaten IS not null and auto_tab2.nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solconseguialch2,
SUM(case when auto_tab2.fechaaten IS null and auto_tab2.nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solsinseguialch2,
AVG(case when auto_tab2.fechaaten is not null and auto_tab2.nombre is not null then DATEDIFF(DAY, auto_tab2.fechacapt, auto_tab2.fechaaten) end) AS numdiasalch2

FROM cec2
left join auto_tab1 on auto_tab1.cec = cec2.cec
left join auto_tab2 on auto_tab2.cec = cec2.cec

group by cec2.cec
order by cec2.cec
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se podra notar, las columnas solconseguialch, solsinseguialch, solconseguialch2, solsinseguialch2 los datos estan erroneos.
¿Alguna idea de lo que esta pasando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que al hacer el JOIN entre las tablas, estás realizando un producto cartesiano que multiplica las filas y genera resultados erróneos. Para corregirlo, es necesario que realices los cálculos de agregación antes de unir las tablas y así obtener relaciones 1 a 1.

```
WITH ctetab1 AS(
    SELECT cec,
            COUNT(DISTINCT id_tab1) as count_tab1,
            SUM(case when  fechaaten IS not null and nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solconseguialch,
            SUM(case when  fechaaten IS null     and nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solsinseguialch,
            AVG(case when  fechaaten is not null and nombre is not null then DATEDIFF(DAY, fechacapt, fechaaten) end) AS numdiasalch
    FROM auto_tab1 
    GROUP BY cec
),
ctetab2 AS(
    SELECT cec,
            COUNT(DISTINCT id_tab2) as count_tab2,
            SUM(case when  fechaaten IS not null and nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solconseguialch,
            SUM(case when  fechaaten IS null     and nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solsinseguialch,
            AVG(case when  fechaaten is not null and nombre is not null then DATEDIFF(DAY, fechacapt, fechaaten) end) AS numdiasalch
    FROM auto_tab2
    GROUP BY cec
)
SELECT c.cec,
       ISNULL( t1.count_tab1, 0) as count_tab1,
       ISNULL( t1.solconseguialch, 0) as solconseguialch,
       ISNULL( t1.solsinseguialch, 0) as solsinseguialch,
       ISNULL( t1.numdiasalch, 0) AS numdiasalch,
       ISNULL( t2.count_tab2, 0) as count_tab2,
       ISNULL( t2.solconseguialch, 0) as solconseguialch2,
       ISNULL( t2.solsinseguialch, 0) as solsinseguialch2,
       ISNULL( t2.numdiasalch, 0) AS numdiasalch2
FROM cec2 c
LEFT JOIN ctetab1 t1 on c.cec = t1.cec
LEFT JOIN ctetab2 t2 ON c.cec = t2.cec
group by c.cec
order by c.cec
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta no la había visto, era por ahí el camino. Con razón me estaba saliendo datos erróneos, chocaban los mismos datos.

Answer (score 1):

te aconsejo manejar ambas consultas por separado y realizar un union, ya que la correlacion te causa duplicados

```
WITH a as(
SELECT USER_NAME.cec2.cec,
COUNT(DISTINCT USER_NAME.auto_tab1.id_tab1) as count_tab1,
SUM(case when USER_NAME.auto_tab1.fechaten IS not null and USER_NAME.auto_tab1.nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solconseguialch,
SUM(case when USER_NAME.auto_tab1.fechaten IS null and USER_NAME.auto_tab1.nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solsinseguialch,
AVG(case when USER_NAME.auto_tab1.fechaten is not null and USER_NAME.auto_tab1.nombre is not null then USER_NAME.auto_tab1.fechacapt - USER_NAME.auto_tab1.fechaten end) AS numdiasalch
FROM USER_NAME.cec2
left join USER_NAME.auto_tab1 on USER_NAME.auto_tab1.cec = cec2.cec
group by USER_NAME.cec2.cec
order by USER_NAME.cec2.cec
), 
b AS (
SELECT USER_NAME.cec2.cec,
COUNT(DISTINCT USER_NAME.auto_tab2.id_tab1) as count_tab2,
SUM(case when USER_NAME.auto_tab2.fechaten IS not null and USER_NAME.auto_tab2.nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solconseguialch2,
SUM(case when USER_NAME.auto_tab2.fechaten IS null and USER_NAME.auto_tab2.nombre is not null then 1 else 0 end) as solsinseguialch2,
AVG(case when USER_NAME.auto_tab2.fechaten is not null and USER_NAME.auto_tab2.nombre is not null then USER_NAME.auto_tab2.fechacapt - USER_NAME.auto_tab2.fechaten end) AS numdiasalch2
FROM USER_NAME.cec2
left join USER_NAME.auto_tab2 on USER_NAME.auto_tab2.cec = cec2.cec
group by USER_NAME.cec2.cec
order by USER_NAME.cec2.cec
)
SELECT * FROM a UNION SELECT * FROM b;
```

comprobacion de los duplicados

```sql
SELECT 
    USER_NAME.cec2.cec, 
    USER_NAME.auto_tab1.nombre, 
    USER_NAME.auto_tab2.nombre
FROM USER_NAME.cec2 
left join USER_NAME.auto_tab1 on USER_NAME.auto_tab1.cec = cec2.cec
left join USER_NAME.auto_tab2 on USER_NAME.auto_tab2.cec = cec2.cec
```

lo realize usando un esquema llamado USER_NAME en oracle, por eso no utilizo la funcion datediff

Comment: [Luis](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/117337/luis-cazares) lo explico mejor

Comment: Probando el código, no me esta agrupando por cec. Me podrías orientar por favor.

Comment: ese codigo esta haciendo un union al final, no esta agrupando, agrega el groupby y las columnas que necesites

Comment: Esta agregado en las consultas la parte de group by USER_NAME.cec2.cec

Comment: me refiero que el resultado que ves, solo esta haciendo un union, puedes agregar el groupby

Comment: sigo sin entender esa parte. Disculpa.

Comment: si ejecutas la consulta que esta en esta respuesta, veras los resultados sin agrupar, ya que el resultado que obtienes es `SELECT * FROM a UNION SELECT * FROM b;` si deseas, puedes agrupar por `cec2.cec` y veras los datos agregados

Comment: en la respuesta de Luis cazares, el si esta agrupando al final